Understanding 夏二月にて四十円の家なれば尤もなり
The below is a diary entry by Natsume Souseki. He rented villa in Kamakura.

思ったよりも汚なき家 也{なり}。夏二月にて四十円の家なれば尤もなり。

I am not sure what the second sentence means. Does 夏二月 refer to Feburary or July and August? I think 尤もなり means "even more (dirty)" right?
Here's my translation attempt: It was a house that is dirtier than I thought. If it were a 40 yen house rented in Feburary, it will look even more dirty.


思ったよりも汚なき家也。夏二月にて四十円の家なれば尤もなり。

Conjunctive particle 「ば」 in classical Japanese:

已然形+ば (順接確定条件) 「～ので」「～から」「～ところ」
未然形+ば (順接仮定条件) 「もし～なら」「もし～たら」

So ～なれば means ～だから、～なので "...so..." "because..., ..."
cf. ～ならば means もし～なら "if..., ..."
「[尤]{もっと}も(な・だ)」 is 形容動詞 and means "reasonable" "quite natural" "no wonder" "makes sense" (≈「当然だ」「道理にかなっている」). For more info and examples, follow the links in this thread:

What does this type of sentence structure (Verb- dictionary form+のも（は）もっともだ) mean

I interpret 夏二月 as なつ ふたつき、[夏]{なつ}(の)[二ヶ月]{にかげつ}, "two months of summer."

思ったよりも汚い家だ。夏の二か月で四十円の家だから、（汚いのは）[尤]{もっと}もだ。

The house is dirtier than I thought. It is 40 yen for two months of summer, so it is no wonder (that it is so dirty).
